# Clarity on the use of pragmarx/firewall package for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

so I've just completed the install of [antonioribeiro/firewall](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall) package for laravel, which essentially allows blacklisting and whitelist of IP address and countries.

I'm working through the section on [Artisan Commands](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall#artisan-commands), but when i try to run 'php artisan firewall:whitelist country:za' I get the following error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "firewall:whitelist" is not defined.                    
  Did you mean one of these?                                      
      firewall:list                                               
      firewall:tables
```

I have done all the necessary installation steps outlined in the documentation.

What am i doing wrong ? should I be using this command elsewhere ?
I am aware that these can be manually entered into the DB, but this functionality would be great to have.

Comment: Did you add `PragmaRX\Firewall\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,` to your providers list in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yes, I've added both PragmaRX\Firewall\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class, to the providers and 'Firewall' => PragmaRX\Firewall\Vendor\Laravel\Facade::class, to aliases. I'm able to run 'php artisan firewall:list' successfully, but none of the other commands below that. It does however say that other 'firewall:' commands are 'exclusive for database usage'. Does this mean they must be executed in a different fashion ?

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, but did you run `php artisan firewall:tables` and `php artisan migrate` as well?

Comment: yes, I ran those commands. I added the middleware group entries and finally ran php artisan vendor:publish when I had finished the config settings.

Comment: Woot. I fixed it. So when you run 'php artisan vendor:publish' it creates a file called firewall.php in the config folder. The value for 'use_database' is set to false by default. I just had to change that to true. All the Artisan commands are now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem:

**SOLUTION:** When you run 'php artisan vendor:publish' it creates a new file called 'firewall.php' in the config directory. This is where you set default options. Simply change 'use_database' to true and the Database specific commands will work.

```
firewall:blacklist
firewall:clear
firewall:remove
firewall:whitelist
```